# Show the specified element when only the specified link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html structure

```
<a href="#" class="dp">Click me</a>

<div class="dp_div" style="display: none;">
  this is the div content
</div>
```

I want to show the hidden div that has a class of "dp_div" when click on a link that has a class of "dp" and then if click to other element (if the current target click element is not '.dp' and '.dp_div'), the .dp_div will be hide, on the contrary, when click either .dp_div or the .dp then do not hide.

This is what I tried so far but sadly not working.

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass("dp") || $(event.target).hasClass("dp_div"))
    {
        alert('either .dp or .dp_div is click!!');
    } else {
        alert("not .dp or .dp_div is click");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You code snippet is  missing a paranthesis

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass("dp") || $(event.target).hasClass("dp_div"))
    {
        alert('either .dp or .dp_div is click!!');
    } else {
        alert("not .dp or .dp_div is click");
    }
});
```

Please see the [fiddle here](http://jsbin.com/gajuqamaqa/1/edit) for a demo

Comment: this works fine but if i use <tr class="dp"> instead of <a href="#" class="dp">, this returns me ""not .dp or .dp_div is click". any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using <tr> ? Please see the updated fiddle, where I used <div> http://jsbin.com/norinujope/1/edit

Comment: I use <tr> because I want to apply it into my table where if someone click the <tr> then that function should trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This code will show the element if the `HREF` (link) is clicked on:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass("dp") || $(event.target).hasClass("dp_div")){
        $('.dp_div').fadeIn();
    } else {
        alert("not .dp or .dp_div is click");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L0LmLquj/

You may use:

`$('.dp_div').show();`

or

`$('.dp_div').fadeIn();`

or even:
`$('.dp_div').toggle();` if you wish to toggle the element upon clickation.

Comment: this works fine but if i use <tr class="dp"> instead of <a href="#" class="dp">, this returns me ""not .dp or .dp_div is click". any ideas?